# Hyperlink tool use in ArcEngine

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, hyperlink

I'm having some difficulties using the hyperlink tool ([ControlsMapHyperlinkTool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ControlsMapHyperlinkToolClass_Class/00160000006v000000/)) in ArcEngine. Does anyone have any experience with it?

It looks like it behaves correctly except that every time a user clicks a hyperlinked feature it shows a message saying "Unable to launch hyperlink". I'm using a "script" hyperlink and it performs fine in ArcMap. It doesn't seem to be trying to execute the script on click. I checked the [IHotlinkExpressionProperties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00120000060v000000) object and the Expression property is set correctly. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant since it's been a while since I've touched ArcEngine, but what version are you using?  I think there were major improvements between 9.3.1 and 10 which would probably make all the difference here.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a file association or system environment variable issue on the users' computers (or Citrix user profile if running through that).

Pick a user guinea pig and see if the script can be executed manually.